# Position an element at center

Tags: css

I want to set an element whose position is absolute at center , means if element`s position are not absolute then we can do like :

```
            margin : 0 auto;
```

But how we can do the same thing for the element whose position is absolute.?

Comment: This might help http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/RMsSh/

Comment: That is only possible if the absolutely positioned element has a fixed width.

Comment: Removed all the tags but CSS, they were irrelevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.target {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;   /* set left */
    width: 500px;  /* give width */
    margin-left: -250px; /* margin-left = width/2  */
}
```

and set its parent as `position: relative`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RMsSh/9/)**

A sample jQuery approach:

```
var width = $('.target').width();
$('.target').css({
    left: '50%',
    'margin-left': -(width / 2)
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RMsSh/11/)**